# Create a sprint based on Filter query in JIRA Agile

Tags: agile, user-stories, sprint

My Customer won't follow sprints but will have releases (4 weeks) only. But i want to create a sprint to generate reports.

I have created a board for agile. But i want to add issues to this board using filter query. Then in Plan tab, i create a sprint and add all the issues to this sprint. Can anyone let me know how to do it.

Or is there any alternative way of creating sprint.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to: 
1. Create your sprint, e.g. 'Sprint 5' 
2. Open your Issue filter.
3. Select Tools > Bulk Change > All Issues.
4. Follow the work flow to Edit the issues, changing their Sprint to 'Sprint 5'

All of your issues will now be quickly assigned to your sprint.